# Wordpress - Archive Custom Post Type just works to default permalink configuration

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, archive, permalinks

I'm building my first plugin and it contains a custom post type (CPT) called "feature". I'm trying to access the "archive" page for this CPT but I get "error 404" using any Permalink Configuration except the default one.

When I use the "Default" configuration for permalinks the "archive" returned is from template and not the one from my plugin. What am I doing wrong?

```
function fmp_create_post_feature() {
register_post_type( 'feature',
  array(
      'labels' => array(
          'name' => 'Features' ,
          'singular_name' => 'Feature',
          'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ) . ' Feature',
          'add_new' => __( 'Add' ) . ' nova',
          'add_new_item' => __('Add').' nova Feature',
          'menu_name' => 'Feature with Modal Popup',
          'all_items' => 'Features',
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'feature' ),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-desktop',
      'supports' => array(
          'title',
          'editor',
          'thumbnail'
       ),
       'taxonomies' => array(
          'feature',
       ),

  )
);
flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'fmp_create_post_feature' );
```

The code above is the cpt registration and the one below the taxonomy registration

```
add_action( 'init', 'fmp_create_tax' );

function fmp_create_tax() {
 register_taxonomy(
    'feature',
    array(
        'label' => 'Feature',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'feature' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    )
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you did not defined `'has_archive' => true,` while registering your custom post type.

As Quoted from WordPress.

> has_archive (boolean or string) (optional) Enables post type archives. 
>   Will use $post_type as archive slug by default. Default: false

Note:

> Will generate the proper rewrite rules if rewrite is enabled. Also use
>   rewrite to change the slug used.

So your register post type array would be

```
register_post_type( 'feature',
  array(
      'labels' => array(
          'name' => 'Features' ,
          'singular_name' => 'Feature',
          'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ) . ' Feature',
          'add_new' => __( 'Add' ) . ' nova',
          'add_new_item' => __('Add').' nova Feature',
          'menu_name' => 'Feature with Modal Popup',
          'all_items' => 'Features',
          'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'feature' ),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive'        => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-desktop',
      'supports' => array(
          'title',
          'editor',
          'thumbnail'
       ),
       'taxonomies' => array(
          'feature',
       ),

  )
);
```

Comment: Noman, thanks for the answer.
You're exactually right ! when I define "has_archive" to true it works perfectly.

Comment: @AndréRocha please accept my answer if it help you ?